# Magento: Associated Product Image showing in product gallery

Tags: php, mysql, magento, standards, product

Associated Product Image showing in product gallery in Magento.
I need to show only product images not associated product image.
How i can able to do that.
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set visibility as `not visible individually` under the general tab of product settings

Comment: If i do that, associated product image not showing on other page.I have to set it visible.thanks for the help.